# Are there examples of Fano manifolds such that Tian's alpha invariant satisfies $\alpha_G(X)=\frac{n}{n+1}$ but without a Kähler-Einstein metric?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

The alpha invariant $\alpha(X)$ of a Fano manifold $X$ of dimension $n$ is defined as the infimum of log canonical thresholds of (effective) $\mathbb{Q}$-divisors $D\sim_{\mathbb{Q}}-K_X$. Similarly, for $G\subset Aut(X)$ a compact subgroup of the automorphism group, one defines $\alpha_G(X)$ considering only $G$-invariant divisors. The alpha invariant has a corresponding analytic definition involving complex singularity exponents of singular hermitian metrics [2, Appendix].

Tian introduced this invariant and proved that the lower bound $\alpha_G(X)>\frac{n}{n+1}$ implies the existence of a Kähler-Einstein metric [1] (in fact, even today it is one of the few sufficient conditions which is checkable in practice). I'd like to know if this theorem is sharp? That is:

**Question:** Are there examples Fano manifolds such that $\alpha_G(X)=\frac{n}{n+1}$ but without a Kähler-Einstein metric?

I'd also be interested in any partial results in the positive direction.

An example I know of with $\alpha(X)=\frac{n}{n+1}$ is a del Pezzo surface of degree $4$ (this is due to Cheltsov [3]), however by Tian's classification of Kähler-Einstein metrics on del Pezzo surfaces [4], such surfaces are known to admit Kähler-Einstein metrics.

References:

[1] G. Tian. On Kahler-Einstein metrics on certain K ̈ahler manifolds with $c_1(M)>0$.

[2] I. Cheltsov, C. Shramov, Appendix by J. P. Demailly. Log canonical thresholds of smooth Fano threefolds.

[3] I. Cheltsov. Log canonical thresholds of del Pezzo surfaces.

[4] Tian, G. On Calabi’s conjecture for complex surfaces with positive first Chern class.

Comment: Can you please give a reference for this statement? Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, I'll add some references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see. THis is more subtle. There is no known example. 
I think it will be impossible or very hard to create one.
Vanya

Answer (score 9):

This question was answered negatively by Kento Fujita [today](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.08261%20*today*) (at least when $G$ is trivial).

**Theorem** (Fujita): If $\alpha(X,-K_X)=\frac{n}{n+1}$, then $X$ is K-stable and hence admits a Kähler-Einstein metric.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not sharp.
General smooth cubic surface with Eckardt point is an example.
Then Aut=Z_2, \alpha_G=2/3 and KE metric exists.
If you want very non sharp example, 
use Kollar's paper http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507289
Du Val del Pezzo surfaces with A1 and A2 singularities are KE.
But their \alpha-invariants are small. 
See paper of Park and Won: Log canonical thresholds on del Pezzo surfaces of degree >=2,
Nagoya Math. J. 200 (2010), 1-26.
Vanya

Comment: If you do not care about G-invariant alpha-invariants, then it is easy to constructs many examples.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, which was for examples where $\alpha = \frac n {n+1}$ and no Kähler-Einstein metric exists.

Comment: Sorry Vanya, perhaps I should have been more clear. Dan is right, what I'd like is an example where $\alpha_G(X)=\frac{n}{n+1}$ but where no Kähler-Einstein metric exists. I'll edit the question to make it clearer. Thanks for the answer, though.